# Type conversion with bit shift (in C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to get how memory allocation works, what happens with addresses and memory while changing types, etc.

I stacked with this string and can't understand what exactly is happening here:

```
(uint32_t)(((uint64_t)addr) >> 32)
```

There is no pointers so I have no guesses how memory allocation is changed here.
Could you explain me, please? Let's imagine that variable "addr" has type DWORD.

Comment: There are no memory operations at all in the expression that you have shown.  It is a pure computation on numbers.  If DWORD has its usual definition (equivalent to `uint32_t`), the result of the computation will always be zero, regardless of the value of `addr`, and both of the casts are pointless.

Comment: There's no "allocation" going on here. And considering that `DWORD` is a 32-bit type what this do is just a complicated way of calculating zero.

Comment: Also I do not understand what you mean by "I stacked with this string".

Comment: There's a simple solution: If you don't know that you need code like this, don't think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addr` is casted to uint64_t; its content shifted 32 bits to the right (with zeros pushed from the left) and the results is cast to uint32_t. It does not seems to make much sense a part of returning zero of type uint32_t in a complex way.

Besides, it has nothing to do with memory allocation, a part of possibly few temporaries on the stack.

Comment: Probably addr 64 bit, otherwise the shift does not make any sense. Cast is added provably for humans reading this code showing that the addr is 64 bit

Comment: It is hard to argue as the whole line seems pretty much meaningless, the only explanations I can give to such a code are: (1) it is an exercise to think about cast and shifts; (2) as far too often in C the programmer uses needless bit tricks on the fake belief that makes the program faster.
However, I think a 32 (or more) bits shift on a 32 bits variable is already undefined. You'd be hard pressed to find a machine that does something weird, yet on this view the cast makes _some_ sense.